# Karabiner: Change double quote to single

Tags: karabiner

Is it possible to replace double quote key to single quote with Karabiner (keyboard customizer for OS X)?

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think so. Look into how the `private.xml` works, which you can open via the `Misc & Uninstall` Tab. However, I think for changing the actual key codes you need seil, but you can probably do it with Karabiner alone by remapping `SHIFT_L + QUOTE`.

You might end up w/ s.th. like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Double Quote to Single Quote</name>
    <identifier>private.double_quote_to_single_quote</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__ 
      KeyCode::QUOTE, ModifierKey::SHIFT_L, 
      KeyCode::QUOTE
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

This is just a guess though, but hopefully brings you in the right direction.

Comment: This example is correct. The only thing you might want to adjust for real usage is change `ModifierKey::SHIFT_L` to `MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_SHIFT`. (Granted most people probably don't hit right shift along with the apostrophe key, but it's possible.)